# How to implement constructors of Class A that has a member variable vector <Class B>,which is its Base function, using initializer_list and template?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, initialization, derived-class

So the problems are:

1. *Class Stan must have a constructor that enables it to recieve and store unlimited nubmer of elements and it has to be implemented using templates. Also, demonstrate it in the main function*
2. *Class Stan must have a constructor that enables it to recieve and store unlimited nubmer of elements and it has to be implemented using initializer lists. Also, demonstrate in main function*
3. *Place class Stan into the namespace Zgrada*
4. *Lets assume that there are 2 types of Stans - Apa & Gar. Within the main function it is necessary to demonstrate polimorphism by implementing getVrsta(); which returns one of the 2 types*

I have no clue how to do more than this.
Thanks for the help!

````
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int Element::brV = 0;



    class Element {
    public:
        string naziv;
        double obujam;
        static int brV;
        Element(string n, double o) : naziv(n), obujam(o) {
    
            if (o > 3.) brV++;
        }

        int getVelikiElementi(){
            return brV;
        }

        void virtual GetVrsta(){
            cout << "Vrsta Stana: ";
        }
    };



    template <class T>               //I think i got the templates_init right
    class Stan : public Element { 
    public:
        vector<Element> Elementi;

        template<class...T>
        Stan(T...arg) : Elementi({arg...}){} 


        Stan(initializer_list<Elementi>) : Element (){} // But this most certainly not
        
        void GetVrsta(){
            
        }
    };
    

int main () {

    Element X("a", 3.);
    Element Y("b", 2.);
    Element Z("c", 1.);

    vector <Element*> E={X,Y,Z}; // initilizer_lista_const_call
    
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `vector<Element*>` holds pointers not `Element`s. Did you actually try to call the constructor of `Stan` ?

Comment: please focus your question on one single issue. The code you posted has many issues, its not clear where to start

Comment: `Elementi` is the name of the member, in some places you confused it with the type `Element`